# Pass all arguments from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating wrapper librabry for some external API.
I have a method which takes about 20 arguments.

so my function looks like:

```
def create_project(
            self,
            client_id: int,
            name: str,
            is_billable: bool,
            bill_by: str,
            budget_by: str,
            code: Optional[str] = None,
            is_active: Optional[bool] = None,
            ...
```

and inside this function I would like to request external api like this:

```
requests.post(url, headers=self.headers, data=data)
```

where data would be dictionary created from all arguments passed in this function.
I could just define function like this `create_post(self, **kwargs)` but we wouldnt know which arguments are required without checking the documentation.

Comment: so `url`, `data`, ... belong also to the signature of `create_project`?

Comment: url is irrelevant here. data is a dictionary with everything that was passed as a arguments

Comment: 20 arguments sounds very unwieldy.  I'd have it take a `TypedDict` of parameters -- that allows the signature/typing to specify the expected params, but also bundles them up into a dict that you can easily pass to your `post` call.

Answer (score 2):

One construct I use from time to time is, as the first line of a function:

```py
def create_project(self, client_id: int, ...):
    allargs = locals()
```

`allargs` contains just the variables that were local on that first line, i.e. the function arguments.

You could then do something along the lines of:

```py
    # example: exclude self, and any other args that you
    # don't want to expose to request.post()

    exclude = {'self', 'super_secret', ...}
    data = {k: v for k, v in allargs.items() if k not in exclude}
    request.post(url, headers=self.headers, data=data)
```

Or whatever suits your needs. **Be aware of mutable variables** if there are any; no deep copy is done in the above.

Two other ways I use this are:

1. For variable inspection in an interactive environment (e.g., Jupyter notebook), without resorting to the debugger:

   ```py
       # some place of interest inside the function:
       global foo
       foo = locals()
   ```

   and, in another cell, after having called the function:

   ```py
   locals().update({k:v for k, v in foo.items() if k in 'var0 var1 var2'.split()})
   ```

   That "brings in" the current context some of the variables of interest. I can then inspect `var0`, `var1`, etc. as they were in the function.
2. To call another function and passing along a bunch of variables:

   ```py
       # (inside function fun_a)
       kwargs = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k in 'arg0 arg1 arg2'.split()}
       fun_b(**kwargs)
   ```

Note that these are meant to be temporary quick & lazy tricks, not for production code!